# Best possible approach(inbuilt sf method, iframe, 3rdpart js libs) to display pdfs for ipads using Visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, pdf, files, ipad

We have scenario where visualforce pages need to display pdfs in ipad browsers. We were able to display attachments but not files.

Is there a way/solution to display pdfs in ipads that works with attachment/files lightning/classic and in any device ?

Comment: 1) Is this using the Salesforce app, or using Salesforce in a browser? 2) Are these PDFs generated on-the-fly in Visualforce or saved as Salesforce Files? 3) Can you show us the code you've tried using so far?

Comment: 1) Salesforce in browser
2) Saved Files and attachments.
3) I tried below code in visualforce, 

$('.pdfViewer').attr('src',/sfc/servlet.shepherd/document/download/'+fileid)

<iframe class="pdfViewer" src=""></iframe>

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to just pop the PDF directly up so the OS will open it? It's really the best PDF-reading experience you can get on an iPad.